# Call a function with two signatures with a union type as argument

Tags: typescript, signature

I have function declared in a library with two signatures:

```js
declare function lookupPropertyValue(key: number, format?: Intl.NumberFormat): string | undefined;
declare function lookupPropertyValue(key: string, caseSensitive?: boolean): string | undefined;
```

And I would like to call it in my TypeScript code with a union type:

```js
function getText(key: number | string) {
    const value = lookupPropertyValue(key); // doesn't work
    if (value === undefined) {
        throw Error('Not found');
    }
    return value;
}
```

But I'm getting an error: "No overload matches this call.". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "*What am I doing wrong?*" literally what the error tells you - the function accepts either a number, or a string, not `number | string`.

Comment: So how could I solve it? Someone suggested to use `const value = typeof key === 'string' ? lookupPropertyValue(key) : lookupPropertyValue(key)` but that looks just redundant to me.

Comment: The *better* option is to change the signature. However, I don't think that option is open for you, if that's a library out of your control.